# Can someone explain why applying map like this in Scala throws and IllegalArgumentException?

Tags: scala, dictionary, illegalargumentexception

Here's a copy of the interpreter commands:

```
scala>val myTable = Array(Array(1))
res30: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(1))

scala> myTable.map(_.map(_.toString))
res31: Array[Array[java.lang.String]] = Array(Array(1))

scala> var result = 0
result: Int = 0

scala> myTable.head
res32: Array[Int] = Array(1)

//note how applying this works
scala> res32.map(elem => if(3> result) result = 3)
res34: Array[Unit] = Array(())

scala> result
res35: Int = 3

//this also works
scala> myTable.map(_.map(_.toString))
res31: Array[Array[java.lang.String]] = Array(Array(1))

//when you combine the double map application and the anonymous function from earlier:
scala> myTable.map(_.map(elem => if(3 > result) result = 3))
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at java.lang.reflect.Array.newArray(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(Array.java:52)
    at scala.reflect.ClassManifest$class.arrayClass(ClassManifest.scala:107)
    at scala.reflect.Manifest$$anon$9.arrayClass(Manifest.scala:152)
    at scala.reflect.Manifest$class.arrayManifest(Manifest.scala:46)
    at scala.reflect.Manifest$$anon$9.arrayManifest(Manifest.scala:152)
    at scala.reflect.Manifest$$anon$9.arrayManifest(Manifest.scala:152)
    at scala.reflect.ClassManifest$.arrayType(ClassManifest.scala:205)
    at .<init>(<console>:45)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
at .<init>(<console>:11)
at .<clinit>(<console>)
at $export(<console>)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:592)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request$$anonfun$10.apply(IMain.scala:828)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.Line$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(Line.scala:43)
at scala.tools.nsc.io.package$$anon$2.run(package.scala:31)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Is this expected behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scala use `java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance` to create arrays dynamically when `map` is called. <s>This method,  [does not accept a size of zero](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html). since, your lambda is returning an empty array of type `Array[Unit]`, which as a size of zero, you get the exception, when calling the outer map.</s>

By the way, in this example, you really should use `foreach` since you are not trying to map the array to another array, but rather to use side-effects:

```
scala> myTable.foreach(_.foreach(elem => if(3 > result) result = 3))

scala> result
res21: Int = 3
```

*Edit:* I misunderstood the problem (See *MatthieuF* answer). The problem is not the size of the array but the type. It is possible to reproduce the problem with just:

```
scala> java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(classOf[Unit], 1)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at java.lang.reflect.Array.newArray(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(Array.java:52)
at .<init>(<console>:8)
...
```

Comment: Yes it does (accept a size of zero). The method being used is: public static Object newInstance(Class<?> componentType, int length) throws NegativeArraySizeException. Not the other one

Comment: Try the following: java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(int.class, 0)

Answer (score 5):

First things first, you should be using foreach, not map, but you already knew that :-)

You are trying to create an array of array of Unit, which gets translated into Void.TYPE in java. This results in the IllegalArgumentException.